# CSS | Animate div height change from it's content going from display:none to block

Tags: html, css

I have a popup div. It has a form, and at the bottom is an error message. The error message goes to display:none when not active. When displayed, it changes the popups size (makes it taller). I want this transition to be smooth and not instant. Here is what I tried :

```
div {
    -moz-transition: height 1s ease-in-out, left .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out, left .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 1s ease-in-out, left .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 1s ease-in-out, left .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out, left .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

This works when I resize divs, but not when switching the div's content from block to none.

EDIT :
There seems to be confusion with what I am trying accomplish. I do not want to animate the display none/block element. I wan't to animate the SIZE (height) of it's PARENT. For instance, when the child suddenly becomes visible, it makes it's parent taller. I do not wan't this height change on the parent to be instant. I want it to be gradual.

Comment: You **can't** animate the `display` property. An element is either seen or not - there are no "in between" steps to animate. You might try `opacity` rather than `display`, but it's difficult to tell with only snippet of CSS.

Comment: @Scott I am not talking about the display property. I wan't to animate the popup height change from something becoming visible.

Comment: @Scott I added an EDIT to my post.

Comment: Your edit doesn't alter my original comment. To put it another way... make the error container not visible by *some other means* rather than using the display property.

Answer (score -1):

That doesn't change your issue. Unless you use javascript somehow, in which case you're better off with jQuery.

If a child pushes a parent larger, there's nothing happening on the parent as far as CSS is concerned, to animate. You'd still want the animation to happen on the child, and hope browsers and internet connections are fast enough to keep up.

All in all, I think you're thinking about this the wrong way. Correct me if i'm wrong.

If all you want is for the error message to visually appear to be enlarging the popup, why not simply put the error outside the popup and avoid a Russian doll nesting mess?

Again, correct me if I'm wrong:

Instead of this:

```
<div> Your popup ...
     <div> Error message </div>
</div>
```

Do this:

```
<div> A container that covers the screen. Also handy for clicking away the       popup, which is behavior many users expect anyway ...
    <div> Your popup </div>
    <div> Your error </div>
</div>
```

And then position the error up against the bottom of your popup, and match both visually.

Answer (score -2):

The above reply is correct, but gives you no alternative. Try:

```
.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
 }
```

Do pay attention to why you are hiding content, and how to deal with it for non-sighted users, this is a good starting point:

http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/

Comment: I am not talking about the display property. I wan't to animate the popup height change from something becoming visible.

Comment: I wan't to animate the popup menu's height change from it's 'child' becoming visible.

Comment: I added an EDIT to my post.